# Keep just one dropdown menu visible at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have a dropdown menu and I want only one item on my menu to be opened at a time, but I'm having trouble getting to the logic to leave only one as true when it is opene state true others are false I tried to create an array with my useState with all my dropdowns, but I'm not able to imagine a solution for it:

**code**

```
  const [dropDownItems, setDropDownItem] = useState({
    dropdown_home: false,
    dropdown_about: false,
  });
  const updateDropDownItem = (dropDownItem, value) => {
    let existingValues = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dropDownItems));
    existingValues[dropDownItem] = value;
    setDropDownItem(existingValues);
  };
 <NavLi
                onClick={() => {
                  updateDropDownItem(
                    'dropdown_home',
                    !dropDownItems.dropdown_home,
                  );
                }}
              >
                <Link to="/">One</Link>
                {dropDownItems.dropdown_home ? (
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a className="active" href="#Create Page">
                        Create Page
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#Manage Pages">Manage Pages</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                ) : null}
              </NavLi>
              <NavLi
                onClick={() => {
                  updateDropDownItem(
                    'dropdown_about',
                    !dropDownItems.dropdown_about,
                  );
                }}
              >
                <Link to="../about">Two</Link>
                {dropDownItems.dropdown_about ? (
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a className="active" href="#Create Page">
                        Create Page
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#Manage Pages">Manage Pages</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                ) : null}
              </NavLi>
```

problem::

[image]

I am not able to think of a solution to leave only one item as true and the others as false ..

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov I go check now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While managing the state variable that corresponds to currently clicked item, you don't seem to be resetting the others to `false`, so your code should rather look something, like:

```
const updateDropDownItem = dropDownItem => {
    const dropDownItemsCopy = {...dropDownItems}
    Object.keys(dropDownItemsCopy).forEach(key => dropDownItemsCopy[key] = key == dropDownItem)
    setDropDownItem(dropDownItemsCopy)
  }
```

With that, you just need to pass exact item being clicked, like below (for every item):

```
onClick={() => updateDropDownItem('dropdown_about')}
```

Following is a quick demo as a proof of a concept:

```js
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      rootNode = document.getElementById('root'),
      menu = ['menu1', 'menu2', 'menu3', 'menu4']

const MenuBar = ({menuItems}) => {
  const [visibleMenu, setVisibleMenu] = useState(menuItems.reduce((r,e) => (r[e] = false, r), {})),
        onUpdateVisibility = item => {
          const visibleMenuCopy = {...visibleMenu}
          Object.keys(visibleMenuCopy).forEach(key => visibleMenuCopy[key] = key == item)
          setVisibleMenu(visibleMenuCopy)
        }
  return (
    <div>
      {
        menuItems.map(item => (
          <span
            key={item}
            onClick={() => onUpdateVisibility(item)}
          >
            {item}
          </span>
        ))
      }
      <br/><br/>
      {JSON.stringify(visibleMenu)}
    </div>
  )
}

render(<MenuBar menuItems={menu} />, rootNode)
```

```css
span {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Hello this way my state is always getting false.

Comment: @MykonSpt : I have found the bug - it was `dropDownItems[key]` instead of necessary `dropDownItemsCopy[key]` inside `forEach()` loop

Comment: Hello thank you very much bro
i like your snippet i'll try to do something like this, could you give me just one more tip? with regard to I will have my li's that will be dropdown menus, but I want only one or two li tags to display content to display the drop down content

Comment: @MykonSpt : I didn't quite get the question. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: basically i will have a menu
with tags like
<li> and I wanted to render my drop down in just 2 or 3 tags <li> I would render my drop down